# YesodAuthEmail could not deduce m ~ HandlerFor site0

Tags: haskell, authorization, yesod, type-families

I'm trying to add

```
instance YesodAuthEmail App
```

to the `Yesod-Postgres` scaffolding (yesod version 1.6) and getting stuck on a compile error.

The relevant code is:

```
instance YesodAuth App where
     type AuthId App = UserId
     ....
     authPlugins :: App -> [AuthPlugin App]
     authPlugins app = [authOpenId Claimed []] ++ extraAuthPlugins
         where extraAuthPlugins = [ authEmail ]

instance YesodAuthEmail App where
    type AuthEmailId App = UserId

    afterPasswordRoute _ = HomeR

    addUnverified email verkey =
        runDB $ insert $ User email Nothing
```

The error I receive is:

`/home/justin/code/yesodemail/src/Foundation.hs:273:11: error:

    • Could not deduce: m ~ HandlerFor site0 from the context: MonadAuthHandler App m
    bound by the type signature for:
        addUnverified :: Yesod.Auth.Email.Email -> VerKey -> AuthHandler App (AuthEmailId App)
....

      Expected type: m (AuthEmailId App)
      Actual type: HandlerFor site0 (Key User)`

Based on the types,

```
getEmail :: AuthEmailId site -> AuthHandler site (Maybe Email) 
type MonadAuthHandler master m = (MonadHandler m, YesodAuth master, master ~ HandlerSite m, Auth ~ SubHandlerSite m, MonadUnliftIO m)
type AuthHandler master a = forall m. MonadAuthHandler master m => m a
```

I would have thought this would compile. What I am misunderstanding?

P.S. I've tried to include everything relevant, but the full Foundation.hs is at https://gist.github.com/hyperpape/39d4d2baf67d3bdbdba45a943e7e0425

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of [`runDB`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.13/yesod-persistent-1.6.0/Yesod-Persist-Core.html#v:runDB) is:

```
runDB :: YesodDB site a -> HandlerFor site a
```

in order to call it in `AuthHandler` you need to lift it to `HandlerFor`.

If I am not mistaken this is what the [`liftHandler`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.13/yesod-core-1.6.5/Yesod-Core.html#v:liftHandler) method from `MonadHandler` is for.

If you compose your `runDB` call with it, it should work:

```
addUnverified email verkey =
    liftHandler . runDB $ insert $ User email Nothing
```

I found a detailed answer to your question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yesodweb/XR4UQHkmQ4A).